# Set background for each quadrant in AnyChart polar charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, radar-chart, anychart

I am creating a polar chart using [AnyChart](https://www.anychart.com/)

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
    // create polar chart
    var chart = anychart.polar();

    var columnSeries = chart.column([
        {x: 'A', value: 28.7},
        {x: 'B', value: 19},
        {x: 'C', value: 17.7},       
        {x: 'D', value: 34.7}
    ]);

    // set series name
    columnSeries.name('Percentage');

    // set title settings
    chart.title()
            .enabled(true)
            .text('Test')
            .padding({bottom: 20});

    // disable y-axis
    chart.yAxis(false);

    // set value prefix for tooltip
    chart.tooltip().valuePrefix('%');

    chart.sortPointsByX(true);

    // set x-scale
    chart.xScale('ordinal');

    // set chart container id
    chart.container('container');

    // initiate chart drawing
    chart.draw();
});
```

```css
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.2.1/js/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Is it possible to add a background for each quadrant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by assigning a palette of the xGrid:

```
chart.xGrid().palette(["red 0.5", "green 0.5", "blue 0.5", "cyan 0.5"]);
```

See a snippet:

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
    // create polar chart
    var chart = anychart.polar();

    var columnSeries = chart.column([
        {x: 'A', value: 28.7},
        {x: 'B', value: 19},
        {x: 'C', value: 17.7},       
        {x: 'D', value: 34.7}
    ]);

    // set series name
    columnSeries.name('Percentage');

    // set title settings
    chart.title()
            .enabled(true)
            .text('Test')
            .padding({bottom: 20});

    // disable y-axis
    chart.yAxis(false);

    // set value prefix for tooltip
    chart.tooltip().valuePrefix('%');

    chart.sortPointsByX(true);

    chart.xGrid().palette(["red 0.5", "green 0.5", "blue 0.5", "cyan 0.5"]);

    // set x-scale
    chart.xScale('ordinal');

    // set chart container id
    chart.container('container');

    // initiate chart drawing
    chart.draw();
});
```

```css
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.2.1/js/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: could you please answer this as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56052829/setting-maximum-and-minimum-xscale-values-in-anychart-graph-results-in-an-except

Answer (score 0):

It is very flexible, you can just set the fill property on your data definition, e.g:

```
var columnSeries = chart.column([
    {x: 'A', value: 28.7, fill: "#990000"},
    {x: 'B', value: 19, fill: "#009900"},
    {x: 'C', value: 17.7, fill: "#000099"},       
    {x: 'D', value: 34.7, fill: "#990099"}
]);
```

For more info, please [refer to the docs](https://docs.anychart.com/Basic_Charts/Area_Chart#appearance)

Comment: I was not looking for `fill`. What I need is to set the background for each quadrant.

Comment: If you mean the background as the chart's property, I'm afraid there is no way in the API to achieve it. The BG is a chart's property and there is nothing to do with the data and its formatting/distribution...
Not sure though.

Comment: the problem is that there is no such thing as a quadrant in these polar charts. It is just the distribution for a 4-valued series

Comment: @VictorLiaFook FYI - you can do that with xGrid palette, see the answer above

Comment: Thats cool @AnyChartSupport. But what about the background? After all, xGrid is about the grid, we can still set the background, and this one we can't really set like that, can we?

Comment: @webster does the solution provided above meet your requirements to set background for every quadrant? Background of the chart fill not only all quadrants, but also the rest space of chart's container (outside polar).

Comment: @AnyChartSupport : Your answer was working perfectly for me!